# Can't call / pass data from django database onto website using built in auth model and a model I created, which is the one I cant query

Tags: python, django, sqlite, authentication, model

Any help would be appreciated, basically I am a beginner and I'm struggling to pull data from  my database. I used the built in auth method from django, which seemingly works ok as I can pull  user data. However as soon as I want to use my Member class I made in models nothing seems to work. Can't output all its data. When looking at the admin page I see authentication and authorisation table and my Members table created in models.py.

When I try pass into the context however nothing is displayed.

My index.html

```
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  Hi {{ user.username }}!
  Hi {{ user.email }}!
  <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a></p>
{% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  Hi {{ all }}!
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}


{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
```

My Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Member
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    all_members = Member.objects.all
    return render(request, 'index.html', context = {'all':all_members})

def ethos(request):
    return render(request, 'ethos.html', {})
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

# Create your models here.

class Member(models.Model):
    phoneNumber = PhoneNumberField()
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    jobDesc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    yearsExperience = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstName + ' ' + self.lastName
```

I can display the username from the auth on index. But anything to do with the Member class as will be displayed when user is logged out is not shown.

I am tempted to start from scratch but time is an element and implementation this far has already proved difficult in some scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

you need a few small changes, first for the user object you need to take it from request, {{request.user}} and a small bug when calling the data from the database:

```
def index(request):
    all_members = Member.objects.all() # here the () !
    return render(request, 'index.html', context = {'all':all_members})
```

in the template:

```
{% block content %}
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  Hi {{ request.user.username }}!
  Hi {{ request.user.email }}!
  <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a></p>
{% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  Hi! {% for person in all %}<p>{{person}}</p>{% endfor %}
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}


{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, however I'm still getting the same result. There doesn't seem to be a dataset to iterate. Its almost certainly to do with the auth process as I see two seemingly seperate datbases (although ive checked with dbviewer and all tables are stored in same db file) on the admin page. I assume there's something that needs allocating between these two entities, tried ".using" to no avail. Also tried thinking about the context dictionary. Maybe using an email as a foreign key which would link the two tables together.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lied within the URLs, through following a tutorial I had set the pattern to render template_as_view rather than view.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).